# Math table and calculations on the same line of the pdf

Tags: tables, math-mode, align

I am kind of a new user with latex math modes and I wanted to ask how can I get the array and the calculations to be on the same line. I tried 
       `\begin{align*}` but there seems to be an error.
The fact is I dont really know what these  `\[` and `\]` are so maybe there hides the solution? Here is how it looks like now and basicly I want to bring them together on the same line

[image]
My code for the array is here.
Thank you in advance!

```
\begin{document}
\[
\textbf{\texten{L}}  =  
\left \vert
    \begin{array}{ccc}
        \hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \\
       x & y & z \\
       p_x & p_y & p_z
    \end{array}
\right \vert
\] $=\hat{x}(yp_z-zp_y)+\hat{y}(zp_x-xp_z)+\hat{z}(xp_y-yp_x)$\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\[` and `\]` enter and exit *display* math mode, while `$...$` is for *inline* math. You are thus putting the matrix in a math display, then closing it with `\]`, going to a new line and writing the expansion of the determinant in inline math. Since you want a single equation there is no need for closing `\]` and writing the rest of the equation on a new line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{L}  =  
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \\
x & y & z \\
p_x & p_y & p_z
\end{vmatrix}
= \hat{x} (y p_z-z p_y) + \hat{y} (z p_x-x p_z) + \hat{z} (x p_y-y p_x)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments

- `\textbf` is , as the name says, a *text* command. You want to use `\mathbf` here. (Actually, you might want to define some vector command which expands to `\mathbf` and which you can change later, if you want.)
- I use the `vmatrix` environment from `amsmath`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution plus the useful comments!

Comment: @Bernard Thx for correcting the typos. Never write an answer before coffee in the morning `;-)`

Comment: And always re-read oneself before posting… which I do not  always think of myself! ;o)